# Website pages are not redirecteed to new domain

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to forward my website to a new domain and want all old pages to be also redirected.
I have done the following.

In my registrar, I have forwarded my old domain to the new domain.

On my old website server, I have added the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old_domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://new_domain.net%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old_domain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old_domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new_domain.net/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

The main site is being redirected correctly. However, when I click on old_domain.com/old_post, I get a blank page.

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: You probably need to remove the redirect from your registrar. They will use their DNS system to resolve your domain and forward it to the new without hitting your old  domain's apache server at all

Comment: Thanks drew010, but I am using the regsitrar nameservers on both sites.

Comment: Exactly, and when you configure a redirect while using their nameservers, they will point the A record to them and then handle the redirect to the new domain from their end, thus never reaching your Apache using the old hostname.

Comment: did you use 301 redirection plugin on your old website ?

Comment: @drew010 I have removed the redirect from my registrar. I will update in few hours if it has worked.

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj no I didn`t use any plugins on my old wordpress site.

Comment: I might have misread the original post and missed the part about the blank page thing.  Let us know if removing the registrar redirect changes anything and if it's still stuck what's wrong

Comment: Then you should need to use it and then your can redirect each page manually from back end.